# Deriving Parseval relation from Parseval identity.

Tags: functional-analysis, parsevals-identity

Consider a given orthonormal $M$ in a Hilbert space $H$. Then $M$ is total iff
$$\sum_k |\left< x,e_k \right>|^2=\|x\|^2$$
holds for all $x\in H$ where $\left< x,e_k \right>$ are the nonzero Fourier coefficients of $x$.

In Kreyszigs Functional Analysis a problem asks to derive from this equality the following:
$$\left<x,y\right>=\sum_k \left< x,e_k \right>\overline{\left< y,e_k \right>}.$$

How would I derive the second equality from the first? Clearly setting $y=x$ derives the first from the second equality, but what about the other direction?

Comment: A physicist would "write $1$ as $\sum |e_k\rangle \langle e_k|$", that is, in mathematics language, decompose $x=\sum \langle e_k |x\rangle e_k$ and similarly for $y$, thus immediately obtaining the second formula. The problem is that nobody assures convergence. This is where the first condition comes in.

Comment: So the point of the first identity is to assure that $x=\sum_k \left< x,e_k \right>e_k$ is a convergent sum?